# Python scraping from a txt web-page

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a large txt file from a website
https://en90.tribalwars.net/map/village.txt

These are the first few lines:

`1,Barbarian+village,508,538,10342642,4208,0`

`2,ckouta+village,507,542,11001011,9761,0`

`3,Bonus+village,464,449,0,1513,1`

`4,Revenge+Will+Be+Sweet,501,532,9202536,9835,0`

`5,OFF,515,501,11158923,5644,0`

I would now like to extract the the first figure from the line that matches with a given third and fourth column. For example: given I'm looking for x = 464 and y = 449 I would want my script to return 3.

I tried parsing the html page with beautifulsoup and then matching the correct line using regex but I cannot make this work.

Comment: You don't need `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: I would recommend to convert the values in page to `csv` file format (comma seprated value), which it looks like btw and then match column-wise with csv editor or python package, no need for beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use brackets and `groups()` in re module.

The following code will enable you to access to the 1st, 3rd and 4th number.

```
import re
pattern = r'(.+),.+,(.+),(.+),.+,.+,.+'
string = '3,Bonus+village,464,449,0,1513,1'
foo = re.match(pattern, string).groups()
print(foo)
```

which leaves you only to compare the 2nd of foo to'464', 3rd of foo to '449'.

---

I saw one of the comments recommending using csv and I believe that is a very rational idea. The equivalent to using csv can be done by using `string.split(',')`

Comment: Thanks! With the pattern you provided and some small tweaks I have got it to work now :)

Comment: There is a missing character (closing quote on line 3) in the code snippet. I can't edit because an edit needs at least 6 characters changes, and this is only one.

Comment: thanks for telling me.
I mended the missing closing quote on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

On that particular case, I would not use regex. This data looks like CSV data (comma separated values) and is very consistent.

My suggestion:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from collections import namedtuple

text = 'https://en90.tribalwars.net/map/village.txt'
content = urlopen(text).read()
lines = content.split('\n')[0:-1]    # last character is an empty string

village = namedtuple('village', ['id', 'name', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'whatever'])

def create_item(line):
    item = village(
        id=line.split(',')[0],
        name=line.split(',')[1],
        x=line.split(',')[2],
        y=line.split(',')[3],
        z=line.split(',')[4],
        whatever=line.split(',')[5]
    )
    return item

lines = [create_item(line) for line in lines]

sample = lines[0]
print sample.id
print sample.name 
print sample.x      # 512
print sample.y      # 529
```

I added a namedtuple too to make it even cooler. The lines contains all the data, and you should be able to write a function to filter based on x and y values.